# i am not able to get data from three table geting error #1111 invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have three tables

```
table A
------------------------------------------
filing_no | pet_name | res_name | court_no
------------------------------------------
1         | xyz      | PQR      |  1
------------------------------------------
2         | abc      | def      |  2
------------------------------------------


Table B
-------------------------------
filing_no |purpose_code|next_date
-----------------------------------
2         | 20         |3/8/2012
-----------------------------------
1         | 21         |3/9/2012
-----------------------------------
2         | 22         |3/10/2012
-----------------------------------
1         | 23         |15/11/2012
-----------------------------------

Table C.
-------------------------------------
purpose_code | purpose_name
-------------------------------------
20           | institution
-------------------------------------
21           | summon
-------------------------------------
22           | proceeding
-------------------------------------
23           | order
-------------------------------------
```

and i want result of particular court like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
filing_no| Pet_name | res_name |purpose_name| next_date
--------------------------------------------------------
1        | xyz      | PQR      | Order      | 15/11/2012
```

i execute the below query and got #1111 - Invalid use of group function ERROR.
please help.

```
select 

    a.filing_no as "File No", a.case_no as "Registration No", a.pet_name as Petitioner, a.res_name as Accused,  
    a.dt_of_filing as "Date of Inst",MAX(b.Next_date) as "Next Date",c.purpose_name as "Case Stage" 

from filing_t a, Daily_proc b, Purpose_t c 
where 
    a.filing_no = b.filing_no 
and c.purpose_code = (
          select purpose_code 
          from Daily_proc 
          where 
              filing_no = a.filing_no 
          and next_date = (
               select MAX(next_date) 
               from Daily_proc 
               where filing_no = a.filing_no
          )
    ) 
and a.court_no = 1 
and a.ci_cri = 2 
and a.status = 'P' 
group by b.filing_no 
order by a.dt_of_filing DESC LIMIT 0 , 2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer Shared by @Devart i am very thankfull to him.

SELECT a.filing_no, a.pet_name, a.res_name, c.purpose_name, b.next_date FROM a
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY filing_no, next_date DESC
       ) t GROUP BY filing_no) b
    ON a.filing_no = b.filing_no
  JOIN c
    ON b.purpose_code = c.purpose_code
WHERE a.court_no = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can only select the columns in `GROUP BY` and results from aggregate functions. For example what `a.pet_name` do you expect to be returned when there are different ones for the same `b.filling_no`?

Comment: thanks to all  this question has been solved by @devart and i have got the desired result..